# How to search a value and replace in array?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

What i need is just replace a specific value in my array, not it all.
Exemple:

```
let ARRAY = ['asd dsa', 'asd', 'dsa asd', 'abc']
```

I need to remove the words "asd" and replace to "abc" like:

```
 ['abc dsa','abc','dsa abc','abc']
```

My attempt:

```
ARRAY.replace(/asd/g, 'abc');
```

but not even in array this works. there is some way to make it?

Comment: Java or JavaScript?

Comment: javascript, sorry

Answer (score 3):

Map the array to a new array, and call `.replace` (or, more appropriately, `.replaceAll`) on every item.

```js
const input = ['asd dsa', 'asd', 'dsa asd', 'abc'];
const result = input.map(
  str => str.replaceAll('asd', 'abc')
);
console.log(result);
```